# mysql_result() not able to find rsource

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code which `echo` the max `id` from my table `challenge` but its giving me this error :

> Warning: mysql_result(): id not found in MySQL result index 6 in D:\xampp\htdocs\challenge.php on line 8

Here's my code:

```
<?php

    require('config.php');


        $result = mysql_query("SELECT max(id) FROM `challenge`");
        $id = mysql_result($result, 0, 'id');
        echo $id;
    ?>
```

My table `challenge` does have an `id` column then why PHP is not able to find.
I do have a correct connection to my database.

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli). [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like it says, you're not returning a column called "id", you're returning one called "max(id)". If you want to refer to the column as "id" use an alias:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT max(id) AS id FROM `challenge`");
```

Note the `AS id`

(Sidenote: as Jay Blanchard says in his comment, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated over security concerns. Look into MySQLi and, as part of it, prepared statements, instead.)

Answer (score 0):

when using aggregate functions like Max, Min try to give an Alias then you can access it in result.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT max(id) as id FROM `challenge`");
```

but this function is slower than  `mysql_fetch_row(), mysql_fetch_array(),` `mysql_fetch_assoc()` and `mysql_fetch_object()`

and secondly you should not use `mysql_*` functions instead use `mysqli or PDO`